# How to control preferred locations of RDD partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Is there a way to set the preferred locations of RDD partitions manually? 
I want to make sure certain partition be computed in a certain machine.

I'm using an array and the 'Parallelize' method to create a RDD from that.

Also I'm not using HDFS, The files are on the local disk. That's why I want to modify the execution node.

Comment: As you may have read in my answer, the question is really about what RDD you're talking about and checking out the sources to see the RDD-specific ways to set the preferred locations. What's the RDD?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm Using an array and and the 'Parallelize' method to create a RDD from that . What do you mean by types of RDDs?

Comment: Also I'm not using HDFS, The files are on the local disk. That's why I want to modify the execution node.

Comment: Updated the answer (see the changes at the bottom). Let me know if things are clearer now. Ask away if not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to set the preferredLocations of RDD partitions manually?

Yes, there is, but it's RDD-specific and so different kinds of RDDs have different ways to do it.

Spark uses `RDD.preferredLocations` to get a list of preferred locations to compute each partition/split on (e.g. block locations for an HDFS file).

> **final def preferredLocations(split: Partition): Seq[String]**
>
> Get the preferred locations of a partition, taking into account whether the RDD is checkpointed.

As you see the method is `final` which means that no one can ever override it.

When you look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L273-L277) of `RDD.preferredLocations` you will see how a RDD knows its preferred locations. It is using the protected [RDD.getPreferredLocations](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L137) method that a custom RDD may (but don't have to) override to specify placement preferences.

```
protected def getPreferredLocations(split: Partition): Seq[String] = Nil
```

So, now the question has "morphed" into another about what are the RDDs that allow for setting their preferred locations. Find yours and see the source code.

> I'm using an array and the 'Parallelize' method to create a RDD from that.

If you `parallelize` your local dataset it's no longer distributed and can be such, but...why would you want to use Spark for something you can process locally on a single computer/node?

If however you insist and do really want to use Spark for local datasets, the RDD behind `SparkContext.parallelize` is...let's have a look at the source code... [ParallelCollectionRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L715) which [does allow for location preferences](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ParallelCollectionRDD.scala#L89).

Let's then rephrase your question to the following (hoping I won't lose any important fact):

> What are the operators that allow for creating a `ParallelCollectionRDD` and specifying the location preferences explicitly?

To my great surprise (as I didn't know about the feature), there is such an operator, i.e. [SparkContext.makeRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L804-L814), that...accepts one or more location preferences (hostnames of Spark nodes) for each object.

> **makeRDD[T](seq: Seq[(T, Seq[String])]): RDD[T]** Distribute a local Scala collection to form an RDD, with one or more location preferences (hostnames of Spark nodes) for each object. Create a new partition for each collection item.

In other words, rather than using `parallelise` you have to use `makeRDD` (which is available in Spark Core API for Scala, but am not sure about Python that I'm leaving as a home exercise for you :))

The same reasoning I'm applying to any other RDD operator / transformation that creates some sort of RDD.