# Is it possible to extend the scheduler of Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I only know the basics of Apache Spark framework. Is it possible to extend Spark scheduler to place its task's operators on different node machines like it is possible in [Apache Storm](https://dcvan24.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/metadata-aware-custom-scheduler-in-storm/)?
On Apache Storm is only implement the `IScheduler` and its methods.

Comment: If the question is if  the API is intended to be extended by the end users, then the answer is most likely negative. And to [quote](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/VOTE-SPARK-24615-SPIP-Accelerator-aware-Scheduling-tp26583p26606.html) Felix Cheung response to acceleration aware scheduling - _Third, the proposal touches on some fairly core and sensitive components, like the scheduler, and I think more discussions are necessary. We have a few comments there and in the JIRA._. Have you rather looked at prefferedLocations?

Comment: Hi @user10958683, thanks for your answer. Seems Flink also have this requirement (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q7NOqt05HIN-PlKEEPB36JiuU1Iu9fnxxVGJzylhsxU/edit#heading=h.k15nfgsa5bnk). About "prefferedLocations", I don't know what it is in Spark. Where I can find some reference? I searched and couldn't find. thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801511/10958683) by [Jacek Laskowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305344/jacek-laskowski).